# Nested lambda foreach with two different lists (one of the list must be final?)

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

Could you help me with writing two nested foreach loops for two different lists where I need to compare specific object attribut stored in both lists?

```java
List<Object1> listOfObject1 = mapper.selectObject1ByName(value1);
List<Object2> listOfObject2 = mapper.selectObject2ByName(value2);

listOfObject1.stream().forEach(object1 -> {
            listOfObject2.stream().forEach(object2 -> {
                if (object1.getCode() == object2.getCode()) {
                    //do something
                }
            });
        });
```

Of course I got this error: "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final" but I can't make any of the list final, because there is some decision logic above where I fill the lists with the correct values and I am writing to the list on more places.

Comment: You could copy your list to a final list if your "do something" does not reassign the list

Comment: Why not just use (enhanced) for loops?

Comment: Otherwise, well you can use plain old for loops

Comment: I was curious if there is some other way than making another copy of the list or using "old" foreach loop. Something nice with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

If implementation of `// do something` part requires either of `object1` or `object2`, then appropriate codes could be collected into a separate set, which is used later to filter the entries in the other list.

For example, if `object2` has to be consumed:

```java
class MyClass {
    static void process(List<Object1> listOfObject1, List<Object2> listOfObject2) {

        // set of codes for Object1 instances
        Set<Integer> codes = listOfObject1.stream()
                                          .map(Object1::getCode)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        listOfObject2.stream()
                     .filter(o2 -> codes.contains(o2.getCode()))
                     .forEach(MyClass::unarySomething);  // method reference
    }

    static void unarySomething(Object2 o2) {
    }
}
```

---

If both `object1` and `object2` are consumed in a method like:

```java
static void binarySomething(Object1 o1, Object2 o2) {
}
```

a map of codes `Map<Integer, List<Object1>> mapCodes` can be created using `groupingBy` and then apply `filter` and `forEach`:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Object1>> mapCodes = listOfObject1
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object1::getCode));

listOfObject2.stream()
             .filter(o2 -> mapCodes.containsKey(o2.getCode()))
             .forEach(o2 -> mapCodes.get(o2.getCode())
                                    .forEach(o1 -> binarySomething(o1, o2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a compare function and use it to compare the data in your lists. I suggest using java [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class. That way the user must define `compare(T o1, T o2)` and `equals(Object obj)` functions.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use hashMap to keep all elements of list2.Then we can iterate list1's  elements and check whether it exists in hashMap or not.

```
final Map<String,Object> mapOfElements= new HashMap<>();
```

Then you can perform required opertaion.

list2.forEach(e->mapOfElements.put(e.getCode(),e));

```
list1
.stream()
.filter(e->mapOfElements.get(e.getCode())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```